# Using VB6.0, How to get itemdata of a selected item in a CheckedListBox?

Tags: vb6, checkedlistbox

Using VB6.0, 
How to get itemdata of a selected item in a CheckedListBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I got it....

```
Dim i as integer 
If myList.Selected(i)  then
    i = chklstCar.ItemData(i)
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ItemData as String
ItemData = myList.ItemData(myList.ListIndex)
```